# Sorting of custom structure not working

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sorting

I have a vector( HLL ) of struct Edge . I want it to sort it according to its weight
usinf C++ std::sort()

```
struct Edge {
    ll aId, bId ;
    double w;
    Edge(){}


    bool operator < (const Edge & E)const
    {
            if(w < E.w) return -1;
            else return 1;
    }

 };

// Here follows many push operations 

sort(HLL.begin(), HLL.end());
for(int i = 0 ; i < HLL.size() ; i ++ ){
         cout << HLL[i].w << endl;
 }
```

From main I called STL sort
This give the following output :(

```
212.132
474.342
300
667.083
500
200
```

Is the value of aId or bId affects ?

I have faced the same problem before
I am using mac 
Code output from Xcode 5.0

Here is The link for my full code written for UVA problem [http://ideone.com/39XIqO][1]

UPD : ANSWERED

Comment: `return -1;` did you mean `return false;` (`return true;` for the other path respectively)?

Comment: Both `-1` and `1` are "true", and your compiler should have barked a pretty significant warning about the translation from `int` to `bool`. if it didn't, crank up your warning levels. `return w < E.w;` should be all you need in that operator.

Comment: Yeah right I should use true / false . Thanks.. I am returning like qsort

Comment: @Matrix.code Fwiw (and barely related only because you mentioned it), even a `qsort` comparator returning `int` should account for a double not-less. I.e. something like `return (w < E.w) ? -1 : (E.w < w);`. If you code a qsort C solution in the future, maybe consider that. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort()` requires a *boolean*, binary predicate which yields a [strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). Your predicate clearly isn't boolean. Interpreting `1` as `false` and `-1` as `true` should yield a strict weak order, though.

Comment: Thanks everyone For answering 
@WhozCraig I will follow your advice , I got it :)